# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: sales_position.created

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm working on a django project where I'm parsing a CSV file to create objects. I'm getting a database error that results in

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: sales_position.created
```

It looks like a database error because before the traceback I get the follwing message:

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: sales_position.created

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Does deleting all migrations except `0001_initial.py` fix this?

Edit:
I have the following 3 classes in `sales/models.py`

```py
class Position(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

class Sale(models.Model):
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position)
    total_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    salesman = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class CSV(models.Model):
    file_name = models.FileField(upload_to='csvs')
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Edit 2:

imported Product class in `sales/models.py`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products', default='no_picture.png')
    price = models.FloatField(help_text='in US dollars $')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: You are trying to create object of sales_position model with not optional field created. Either add null=True in your field and run makemigrations and migrate or ensure that all your rows in CSV have this fields as not null

Comment: thanks @TrueGopnik I have edited the initial post and added the relevant classes. I tried adding null=True somewhere yesterday and received an error, where exactly would I put the null=True value?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: as @TrueGopnik pointed out , you should change this line models.DateTimeField(blank=True) in your Sale  class to models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True) . then run makemigrations and migrate command.  I also see you have Product as FK in your Position class . but i don't see it defined from the code

Comment: I have updated the code with ```models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)``` and also ran the migrations but still getting the same error. I have also added a second edit showing the imported Product class. 

What else could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign null value to not nullable field `created` in your `Position` model, to make your code work either ensure that data in your CSV file has `created` with some value or add `null=True` in your `Position` model `created` field

```
class Position(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

After that you should run `python manage.py makemgirations`  and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: omg it's working now, thank you so so much @TrueGopnik and Manoj for your help - thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Delete your all migration folders.

And try these 3 commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname
python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001 # you will get this value after makemigrations.
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: thanks will do, the appname is the name of the folder where I start the server?

Comment: I think I have several migrations ``` Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, customers, products, profiles, reports, sales, sessions``` but they are all in the ```/src``` folder, so I would write ```python manage.py makemigrations src``` correct? It's such a noob question but I'm afraid to break everything

Comment: I want to try what you suggest but I'm not sure what to put into appname should this be my source folder /src like so: ```python manage.py makemigrations src``` ?

Comment: No no. It's not a source folder. it's a app in django project

Comment: You don't know what is app in django?

Comment: yes, just getting started also with the terminology, but I think that my apps in this case would be the following that get listed when I run migrations: ```Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, customers, products, profiles, reports, sales, sessions``` Is this correct? In which case I simply would have to run ```python manage.py makemigrations sales```

Comment: yes correct. Before makemigrations, migrate it using python manage.py migrate and then do makemigrations

Comment: it's working now, thank you so much @Manoj Tolagekar I'm feeling like I'm making progress in learning this thanks to you, much appreciated I really was 3 afternoons busy with this, first looking into complete direction. But now it's working - thank you :)

Comment: is there a way to accept both? I accepted his first because for people reading this it will be easy to understand the problem fix only by reading his later reply, so for general quality of thread it's better if I accept his answer

Comment: Refer this for acceptance of answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers

Comment: There is no any other ways to accept multiple answers

Comment: that's a good threat for future reference as well. It is recommended to select the answer that is actually used, in this case I didn't run ```python manage.py makemigrations sales``` but ```python manage.py makemigrations sales``` as @TrueGopnik suggested, combined to the amendments in the ```class Position``` so that I should select his reply. But really appreciate your help!